# Extend available reference tag properties for Entry

Tags: element, reference-tags

Is it possible to create a new property on an Entry element for use in a reference tag? I.e.

`{entry:[id]:customProperty}`

I have tried creating a custom behavior as outlined [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/extending-system-components.html#behaviors), but I believe that creates a new *method* rather than a property, because it does not seem to work in a reference tag.

```php
class CustomBehavior extends Behavior
{
    public function customProperty(): string
    {
        return 'whatever';
    }
}
...

{entry:[id]:customProperty} //--> Outputs the entry URL rather than 'whatever' (Presumably because it does not recognize 'customProperty')
```

Is there any way to extend what is available for use in a reference tag without having to create an entirely new element type?